# Can I ask a list of questions based on how code really works?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Actually on Stack Overflow most of the time we delicately ask one
problem at a time.

But what if I or some one other have a **list of problems** and really want to know?

**Mainly I focused on how to ask a list of questions.**

A list of programs that based on what is the output of this code.
How this program really work.
etc.

Comment: all those 4 sound as way too broad / opinion based.

Comment: It is just an examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not appropriate to ask multiple questions in a question like that.  You should be asking a *single* question.

Additionally, every single one of your example questions are either Too Broad, Primarily Opinion based, or both, so even asking them individually wouldn't be appropriate either.

Comment: Ok I agreed.
But if I have 10 to 20  questions but the length of questions are 2 lines or 3 lines.
e.g. var a = 2 && 3;  console.log(a);
then?

Comment: @AnkitPandey Neither of those things makes posting multiple different questions in a single question appropriate.  It *is* an indication that you probably shouldn't be using SO though; if you really need to know that much, about something so simple, odds are you should be looking to books/tutorials/etc. because you're looking for basic background information on core concepts (at least by the looks of it) which is better suited to those media.

Comment: Awesome response helped me to build my mindset.

Comment: Could you please close my question.

Comment: @AnkitPandey You closed it yourself yesterday.